# How Can I measure Jenkins Build Performance?

Tags: jenkins, devops

I want to monitor jenkins build performance .I want to find out a way using which I can find out how jenkins is doing.Please suggest me good ideas.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the Jenkins page for any build job, there is a "Trend" link at the top of the list of builds on the left that tracks execution time for each build.

[image: Trend link]